# Does Google value links to a page's named anchors (#) as equal to links to the page w/o the anchor?

Tags: seo, google, links, backlinks

Occasionally my site gets links directly to a sub-section of a page via a named anchor, e.g. /mypage.html#section1

Does Google give this link equal weight as a link to /mypage.html?

Comment: I used this method and got some good jumps in serps! i had 6 #anchors on one page and did around 2000 backlinks just to those. I whent from page 34 to page 3 over a 3 week period.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't affect the rankings. That only helps the browser identify a portion of the page so it can properly display it when the page loads.

(If Google ever starts ranking portions of pages then it might come into play but for now that's just fun stuff to think about).

Comment: Not to question your competence in any way. But ever since I read more in the context of the SEO business (I'm just a small C# developer trying learn more about SEO), I hear everyone telling you how this and that is. Virtually no one is able to proof it's statements. This is OK, since probably even Google employees could not tell you everything about how this or that influences a site's rank. I just whish that people add a "in my humble opinion" to these statements. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: when you say it doesn't affect rankings, do you mean it has the same value to Google with our without the anchor?  Or that a link with an anchor doesn't count at all in the backlink profile for the page (i.e. same as no link at all)?

Comment: @JeremyB, I mean you get full value for that link.

Comment: do you mean Google PR flows into that link too? Maybe some references where you read about this stuff would be nice.

Comment: These links are equivalent; linking to "/mypage#anchor" is seen as the same as linking to "/mypage". 

It's different if you use #! instead of # (#! is for [AJAX-crawling](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/) URLs that are indexed separately).